# move filename with ()s using svn

Tags: svn, command-line, mv

How can I move a file with ()s in its name using svn. I tried:

```
svn mv https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/semiosnet/Test Protocol\ \(office\).docx https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/semiosnet/Repeaters_Network/Test Protocol\ \(office\).docx
svn: Cannot mix repository and working copy sources
```

which apparently doesn't seem to work. Any hints?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you forgot to put a backslash before the space in `Test Protocol`. Alternately, you can put quotes around the file names. I recommend avoiding spaces in filenames for this reason.

Comment: hoops, it would help if I actually read what I wrote! Thanks Greg! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked:

```
svn mv https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/semiosnet/Test\ Protocol\ \(office\).docx https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/semiosnet/Repeaters_Network/Test\ Protocol\ \(office\).docx
```